# Kinect World Coordinates

Tags: c#, coordinates, kinect, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to compute the x-, y- and z-Coordinate of a point selected by the user.
My program shows the Color Stream Image and the depth stream image and the user is able to select two points of interest. My program then should calculate the distance beteween the two point. That for I need the coordinates of the point in mm. So my plan was to map the frame to a SkeletonPoint Structure so I can just read the informations, provided by the kinect sensor.
My Question now is, if I'm doing right or if I'm missing something in my code.
The problem is that I sometimes get negativ coordinates for some point in x and y axis, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

```
   SkeletonPoint[] mySkeletonArray;     

    private void SensorDepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (DepthImageFrame dFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            if (dFrame != null)
            {
                dFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(myDepthArray);
                mySensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthFrameToSkeletonFrame(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30, myDepthArray, mySkeletonArray);


                this.myDepthBitmap.WritePixels(
                    new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.myDepthBitmap.PixelWidth, this.myDepthBitmap.PixelHeight),
                    this.colorPixels,
                    this.myDepthBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
                    0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Mouse_ClickTest(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Point myMousePosition = e.GetPosition(DepthImage);
        double xpixel = myMousePosition.X;
        double ypixel = myMousePosition.Y;
        int xpos = (int)xpixel;
        int ypos = (int)ypixel;
        int depthWidth = mySensor.DepthStream.FrameWidth;
        int depthIndex = xpos + (ypos * depthWidth);
        SkeletonPoint mySkeletonArray = this.mySkeletonArray[depthIndex];
        float zpos = mySkeletonArray.Z;
        float xp = mySkeletonArray.X;
        float yp = mySkeletonArray.Y;
        }
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense you could get negative values for X & Y; The (0;0) point of the kinect is situated in the center of the screen.

Comment: @KevinCloet is correct. There can be some confusion between x&y image coordinates and x&y spatial coordinates. Note that in spatial coordinates, (x,y,z) = (0,0,0) is where the Kinect is, and z increases in the direction the Kinect is looking.